# Opening a file on unix using c++

Tags: c++, unix

I am trying to open a file in c++ and the server the progam in running on is based on tux.

```
string filename = "../dir/input.txt"; works but
string filename = "~jal/dir1/dir/input.txt"; fails
```

Is there any way to open a file in c++ when the filename provided is in the second format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `~jal` expansion is performed by the shell (bash/csh/whatever), not by the system itself, so your program is trying to look into the folder named `~jal/`, not `/home/jal/`.

I'm not a C coder, but `getpwent()` may be what you need.

Comment: I meant duh by me not the poster of the question.

Comment: Magnus, $HOME contains *your* homedir - and ~jal expands to the homedir of user 'jal'.

Comment: 2Magnus: I'm not sure about $HOME, if program will run via 'su', for example

Comment: you were almost right, you omitted only  one sign /, instead of "~jal/dir1/dir/input.txt"  it should look like "~/jal/dir1/dir/input.txt"

Answer (score 9):

You could scan the string, replacing `~user` by the appropriate directory.

The [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html) function [`wordexp`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) does that, and a few other things

- variable substitution, like you can use `$HOME`
- optional command substitution, like `$(echo foo)` (can be disabled)
- arithmetic expansion, like `$((3+4))`
- word splitting, like splitting `~/a ~/b` into two words
- wildcard expansion, like `*.cpp`
- and quoting, like `"~/a ~/b"` remains that

Answer (score 3):

Here is a ready piece of code, that performs this task:

> [How do I expand `~' in a filename like the shell does?](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/2.9.shtml)